# unable to add application insights to service fabric stateless asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to add application insights to a project with the following guide.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-monitoring-aspnet

my project is a service fabric service => .net framework => stateless asp.net core as following:
[service fabric project menu](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi0vu7OhebhAhUILewKHVw8BcoQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodetrest.com%2Fbootstrap-stateless-service-service-fabric-net-core-ioc&psig=AOvVaw2akLT_zrnJT-KCLXGpnqlv&ust=1556102931259572)

the service fabric that contains the project works and published already.
Now when I add application insights and run the service fabric locally it is compiled and runs but asp.net service doesn't run.
in the diagnostic events I see about a minute after I start the service fabric the following health report error stack trace that claims a null reference for basePath:

```
{
  "Timestamp": "2019-04-23T14:01:00.9644622+03:00",
  "ProviderName": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric",
  "Id": 54430,
  "Message": "EventName: StatelessReplicaNewHealthReport Category: Health Partition=4d20cbee-372e-42d1-952e-738538152b1e StatelessInstance=132004907032061609 SourceId=System.RA Property=ReplicaOpenStatus HealthState=Warning TTL=922337203685477ms SequenceNumber=132004908536921071 Description='Replica had multiple failures during open on _Node_0. API call: IStatelessServiceInstance.Open(); Error = System.ArgumentNullException (-2147467261)
    Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: basePath
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String basePath)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.DefaultApplicationInsightsServiceConfigureOptions.Configure(ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions options)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.TelemetryInitializers.ComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer..ctor(IOptions`1 options)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ApplicationInsightsExtensions.<>c.<AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry>b__13_1(IServiceProvider provider)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
       at Micro [Truncated]' RemoveWhenExpired=False SourceUTCTimestamp=04/23/2019 14:00:53 ",
  "ProcessId": 10100,
  "Level": "Informational",
  "Keywords": "0x4000000000000001",
  "EventName": "HM",
  "ActivityID": null,
  "RelatedActivityID": null,
  "Payload": {
    "eventName": "StatelessReplicaNewHealthReport",
    "category": "Health",
    "eventInstanceId": "\"ae7ebe56-19d6-4c36-a6dd-5c12e9a3d36e\"",
    "partitionId": "\"4d20cbee-372e-42d1-952e-738538152b1e\"",
    "replicaId": 132004907032061609,
    "sourceId": "System.RA",
    "property": "ReplicaOpenStatus",
    "healthState": 2,
    "TTLtimespan": 922337203685477,
    "sequenceNumber": 132004908536921071
  }
}
```

]

I tried to inject asp.net core configuration inside the ConfigureAppConfiguration method (thanks to this article https://marcinjuraszek.com/2018/10/asp-net-core-configuration-when-running-as-service-fabric-service.html) but it seems to set the base path 
for the asp.net core configuration but not to application insights.